# Trigonometry inequality for sine of 5 angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given $5$ positive angles $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ such that  $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=2\pi$, show that:
\begin{align}
0 &\le \sin(x_1+x_2) + \sin(x_2+x_3) + \sin(x_3+x_4) + \sin(x_4+x_5)+\sin(x_5+x_1) \\
&\le \sin(x_1)+\sin(x_2)+\sin(x_3)+\sin(x_4)+\sin(x_5).
\end{align}

I was able to show it for $2$ and $3$ angles, but then I got stuck.

Any help would be appreciated!

sin (x1+x2) = sin x1 cos x2 + cos x1 sin x2 $\le$ sin x1 + sin x2

Comment: Please edit your post to include your demonstration for $2$ or, better, for $3$ angles, and point out where/why you don't think this generalizes to $5$ angles.

Answer (score 2):

Proof of the first inequality

$$S=\sin(x_1+x_2) + \sin(x_2+x_3) + \sin(x_3+x_4) + \sin(x_4+x_5)+\sin(x_5+x_1) \ge 0 \tag{1}$$

in the following case :

$$\text{(H)   for any } k, \ 0<x_k<\pi$$

Let us give a geometric interpretation allowing to establish (1).

Under hypothese (H), angles $x_k$, having their sum equal to $2 \pi$, can be interpreted as "deviation angles" $(\overrightarrow{A_kA_{k+1}},\overrightarrow{A_{k+1}A_{k+2}})$ in a certain pentagon $A_1A_2\cdots A_5$ (see figure).

[image]

The angles of the associated pentagram (= five branches star) are:

$$y_k:=\pi-(x_k+x_{k+1})$$

The sum of angles $y_k$s is $5 \pi - (2\pi+2\pi)=\pi$ (it is a known result : see a "dynamic proof" [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17703)).

As all the angles $y_k$ are such that :

$$0 \le y_k \le \pi$$

we have :

$$\sin(y_k)=\sin(\pi-(x_k+x_{k+1}))=\sin(x_k+x_{k+1}) \ge 0$$

Therefore, sum $S$ is $\ge 0$ (in fact  $>0$ : do you see why ?)